# инициализация массива swift

Tags: массивы, swift

есть ли какой-то способ автоматизировать заполнение массива значениями литералов?

Например, нужно создать новый массив и заполнить его значениями. Здесь их 10, но может быть и 100, 200.

467940 
551317 
908604 
946391 
742214 
568555 
897137 
225051 
686493 
228161 
344952

Вручную, в смысле копипастом, это делать утомительно, возможен ли какой-то цикл, чтобы добавить в массив все эти числа?

И да, числа идут именно столбцами.

---

кажется я понял. Вот для чего полезны обсуждения))

Надо вначале скопипастить все значения в строку. Потом использовать функцию  split или components, которые и разбивают строку на отдельные значения, и одновременно преобразуют её в массив значений. А там дальше уже преобразовать String в Int.

Отлично! Давно хотел решить эту задачу. Спасибо за содействие!

Comment: Откуда будут приходить значения?

Comment: вот так в столбике и будут

Comment: будет список значений в файле

Comment: так что, получается вариантов нет?

Comment: вся проблема в том что вопрос не понятен, поэтому и ответов маловато, правильно заданный вопрос - половина ответа. Я правильнейшей понял что у тебя есть файл в котором есть список значений, тебе нужно с этого файла достать эти значения и занести в массив?

Comment: да, примерно так. Есть список значений, которые могут быть в отдельном файле, например, в текстовом, или в ворде, или просто на веб-странице. Проблема в том, что они идут столбиком и без запятых, если я просто их копипастом вставлю в массив, то потом надо вручную проставлять запятые. И если таких значений несколько десятков, то это трудозатратно. Отсюда и вопрос, как их вставить в массив? Знаю конечно про функцию аппенд, но как ее здесь применить, ведь она берет значения уже из чего-то, а в данном случае этого чего-то еще нет.

Answer (score 2):

Вот решение, которое найдено в результате этого обсуждения. Есть список цифр, которые находятся не в файле, а просто написаны на странице сайта. Причем написаны именно так, как показано ниже, столбиком и без разделителей запятых. Если бы они были в файле, или хотя бы в строку и с запятыми, этих проблем бы не было или были бы другие задачи.

Эти числа нужно использовать для решения определенной задачи внутри программы. Вначале хочешь не хочешь приходится их копипастить и вставлять в программу в виде переменной типа String.

```
let stringOfNumbers = """
467940
551317
908604
946391
742214
568555
897137
225051
686493
228161
344952
"""
```

Причем, это не простая строка, а мульти, которая появилась в последних версиях Swift. В синтаксисе у нее две тройные кавычки, которые к тому же пишутся в отдельную строку.

Далее эта строка преобразуется в массив строк с помощью функции components.

```
var arrayString = stringOfNumbers.components(separatedBy: "\n")
```

Здесь в качестве разделителя, по которому строка разбивается на подстроки, указывается символ перевода строки. Удобная, кстати, функция - и строку разбивает, и массив сразу создает, и разделители можно использовать разные. С её помощью получаем следующий массив типа  String:

```
["467940", "551317", "908604", "946391", "742214", "568555", "897137", "225051", "686493", "228161", "344952"]
```

Затем с помощью цикла преобразуем массив типа String в массив типа Int.

```
var arrayInt: [Int] = []

for number in arrayString {
    let numbers = Int(number)
    arrayInt.append(numbers!)
}
```

В результате получаем массив типа Int:

```
[467940, 551317, 908604, 946391, 742214, 568555, 897137, 225051, 686493, 228161, 344952]
```

P.S. На последнем шаге пробовал использовать функцию map, но пока не получилось. Буду благодарен, если кто подскажет.

И еще немного кода, таким как я новичкам будет полезно как пример и как готовое решение. А именно - ниже функция, которая включает в себя вышеприведенный код. Удобно использовать в нужных случаях.

```
func transformStringToArrayInt(stringOfNumbers: String) -> [Int] {

    let arrayString = stringOfNumbers.components(separatedBy: "\n")

    var arrayInt: [Int] = []

    for number in arrayString {
        let numbers = Int(number)
        arrayInt.append(numbers!)
    }
    return arrayInt
}
```